# iOS sdk - Feed Dialog styling is wrong and does not close after posting

Tags: facebook-graph-api, delegates, dialog, feed, facebook-ios-sdk

Trying to add a simple dialog to an iOS app I am working on and running into a couple of strange behaviors.

Using:

```
[facebook dialog:@"feed"
        andParams:params
      andDelegate:self];
```

Yields the following dialog:

[image]

This is on the simulator or the actual device.  Please note the strange buttons and their location.  The dialog will post correctly on the wall, but the dialog does not close.  Instead, I get a JavaScript message:

> window.location.href="fbconnect://success?post_id="

And neither delegate (`dialogDidComplete` or `dialogCompleteWithUrl`) fires.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally found it. The user agent was being overridden in the appdelegate.  This was causing Facebook to send back the incorrect data.